How to initialize a reference while initializing a constructor
So I am working on this C++/PLC project interacting with Hardware.
Due to the nature of my program and the fact that the C++ code gets compiled for PLC I cannot use pointers but can however use references.
My goal is to create an object that has true references to data that gets modified by other threads/ Hardware.
My idea is to link these data-structures to the object by mirror the datatype and creating a link through reference to them.
something along the lines of :
class Node_example {
public:
  boolean data1 = true;
  int16 val1 = 0;
  struct_type1_in &struct_name1_in;
  struct_type1_out &struct_name1_out;
  struct_type2_in &struct_name2_in;
  struct_type2_out &struct_name2_out;
  Node_example(struct_type1_in &struct_name1_in_real_var,
               struct_type1_out &struct_name1_out_real_var,
               struct_type2_in &struct_name2_in_real_var,
               struct_type2_out &struct_name2_out_real_var) {
    struct_name1_in = struct_name1_in_real_var;
    struct_name1_out = struct_name1_out_real_var;
    struct_name2_in = struct_name2_in_real_var;
    struct_name2_out = struct_name2_out_real_var;
  }
};

Obviously that is not possible because I need to initiate a reference when creating it.
I stuck with 4 structs for now because the number is not relevant. What is important is that during runtime I need the modifications happening on the structs I give to the constructor while creating the object to be reflected internally within the object so that It always has the realtime data.
So Is there a way to initialize these references during construction or a way I can achieve similar results without resorting to pointers.
Thank you for your time

I tried operating with pointers and it ended up crashing my application. Contacting the expert of the system I am working on resulted in them telling me to use references and not use pointers because the data is exchanged every cycle and that the system does not know how to handle addresses as it needs the data in the memory.

Tried creating a struct of references of this sort:


struct io_linker {
  struct_type1_in struct_name1_in;
  struct_type1_out struct_name1_out;
  struct_type2_in struct_name2_in;
  struct_type2_out struct_name2_out;
}
io_linker create_linkPort(struct_type1_in &struct_name1_in_real_var,
               struct_type1_out &struct_name1_out_real_var,
               struct_type2_in &struct_name2_in_real_var,
               struct_type2_out &struct_name2_out_real_var) {
    io_linker ports;
    ports.struct_name1_in = struct_name1_in_real_var;
    ports.struct_name1_out = struct_name1_out_real_var;
    ports.struct_name2_in = struct_name2_in_real_var;
    ports.struct_name2_out = struct_name2_out_real_var;

    return ports;
  };

Then called it as follows :
  io_linker test_IO =
      create_linkPort(struct_name1_in_real_var, struct_name1_out_real_var,
                      struct_name2_in_real_var, struct_name2_out_real_var);

It was not successful. I may have sucessfully created such struct but It did not update so it was not really linked to real data. I am fairly new to c++ so I get confused a bit

Here is some more on the topic of constructors and class member initializer lists: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

References need to be initialised in the constructor initialiser list, not in the constructor block.  e.g. with one argument and reference  Node_example(struct_type1_in &struct_name1_in_real_var) : structname1_in(name1_in_real_var) {}

The distinction between initialization and assignment is very important in C++.
